# python script from crontab vs console : print and logging ordered differently

Tags: python, logging, cron

From this python script:

```py
import logging

print('normal print')
logging.error('logger test error')
```

If I run this script from command line I get:

```
$ python3 ./test.py
normal print
ERROR:root:logger test error
```

Now if I set up a cron job with the same script as follow:

```
25 10 * * * python3 ~/test.py
```

I get the following email:

```
...
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
...
Date: Fri,  8 Oct 2021 10:25:01 +0200 (CEST)

ERROR:root:logger test error
normal print
```

We see that the output is reversed.
What's happening here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an eligible answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182537/write-python-stdout-to-file-immediately

Basically, I suppose that cron redirects the command output somewhere to generate the email and that buffering is happening - which is not the case for console output. Here, print()'s output is buffered (eg. not flushed). However, `logging` *does* flush the stream after each call.